# How do I fix this error in with deps.edn file?

Tags: clojurescript, edn

I have created a project called `tutorial` with a `deps.edn` file in it. I also have a `core.cljs  file` in `tutorial/src/appy`.

When I run the command `clj -m cljs.main --compile appy.core --repl` following a tutorial I get an error.

`Error building classpath. Error reading edn. Map literal must contain an even number of forms (C:\Users\...\tutorial\deps.edn)`

The content of the deps.edn file is

```
{:deps {org.clojure/clojurescript {:mvn/version "1.10.773"}}
:paths ["src"]}
```

I understand the error but not why it is generated.

Comment: Are you sure, that you have pasted the deps.edn file that produces the error? Have you left out things for your MVE? Because this deps.end will not produce the error. The error states, that you have a missing value for a key in your map literal.  E.g. something like `{:a :b :c}`

Comment: Perhaps you have some control characters in there instead of just whitespace? See if your editor has some way to "show invisible characters".